# SPFx collapse current navigation sub sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I have the new SharePoint experience enabled in our tenant in one of our site collections. It works beautifully, however the current navigation changed at the root site collection level:

[image: Subsites are expanded]

By default, the sub sites are listed, but they expanded to show their current navigation nodes as well. Since we have about 20 sub sites, the navigation becomes quite long, and renders it somewhat useless for users. Is there a way to have the sub sites collapsed by default?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this has been changed recently:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Can-you-set-the-Quick-Launch-Menu-as-to-default-as-collapsed/m-p/136728/highlight/false#M12380

And I'm now looking for the opposite things: expanding the menu by default...

Comment: You are correct.. I noticed the change in my environment last week as well. I think it would be great if there could be an option to choose one or the other